# Wireshark filter with "less than" doesn't work

Tags: wireshark

I want to create a Wireshark filter which displays all packets which are

- DTLS packets
- **as well as** UDP packets sent from or to a port number between 1234 and 1250

I have tried to use the following filter:

`dtls || (udp.port >= 1234 && upd.port <= 1250)`

Wireshark however shows all kind of packets, e.g. DNS packets from port 52795 to 53, which is completely out of range for the UDP filter part and is not a DTLS packet.

What am I missing, what's the correct filter expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common mistake.  `udp.port` can be thought of as a sort of macro for `udp.srcport or udp.dstport`, meaning that as long as either one is larger than 1234 or either one is less than 1250, the filter, as written, will match the packet.  I think what you want is:

```
dtls || ((udp.srcport >= 1234 && udp.srcport <= 1250) || (udp.dstport >= 1234 && udp.dstport <= 1250))
```

You might want to create a Wireshark [Display Filter Macro](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChDisplayFilterMacrosSection.html) to help simplify that expression.  For example, suppose you created the following macro:

```
((udp.srcport >= $1 and udp.srcport <= $2) or (udp.dstport >= $1 and udp.dstport <= $2))
```

Then you could apply this filter:

```
dtls || ${udp_portrange:1234;1250}
```